# ambiguous overload for 'operator+' when typecasting from unsigned char to a fixed point data type

Tags: c++, vivado, vivado-hls

I implementing an image processing algorithm on vivado hls, as a part of optimization, I am trying to change the floating point representation into fixed point representation.

Here is the part where it is going wrong

```
#include <ap_fixed.h>
unsigned char win[3][3];
typedef ap_ufixed<11,8> fix;
struct pixel_f
{
    fix r;
    fix g;
    fix b;
};
pixel_f new_pix;
.
.
.
.
.

new_pix.r = ((fix)(win[1][0] + win[1][2]) / 2)+0.5;
```

when I tried to execute it, it is giving me an error saying

```
demosiac_core.cpp:16:49: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator+' (operand types are 'ap_fixed_base<11, 8, false, (ap_q_mode)5u, (ap_o_mode)3u, 0>::RType<32, 32, true>::div {aka ap_fixed<12, 9, (ap_q_mode)5u, (ap_o_mode)3u, 0>}' and 'double')
   new_pix.r = ((fix)(win[1][0] + win[1][2]) / 2)+0.5;
```

can someone help me with any suggestions related to why it is going wrong and what can be done to make this work??

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you have an `operator+` overload for the `ap_ufixed` template class and `double`?

Comment: On another note, whenever you "need" to use C-style casting in C++, you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the header files it seems the problem is that the `ap_ufixed` class has both a constructor that takes a double i.e. `fix::fix(double)`, and an operator that converts to a double i.e. `fix::operator double()`. But it does not define an addition operator that takes a fix and a double, i.e. there is no `operator+(fix, double)`.

So when code like this is being compiled

```
fix x = ...;
double y = ...;
fix z = x + y;
```

the compiler doesn't know whether to convert `y` to `fix` and add two `fix` values, or whether to convert `x` to a double and add two `double` values. That what the ambiguity in the compiler error message is refering to.

The solution is to say precisely what you want, if you want that addition to add two `fix` values then write this

```
new_pix.r = ((fix)(win[1][0] + win[1][2]) / 2)+ fix(0.5);
```

if you want the addition to add two `double` values (seems less likely) then write this

```
new_pix.r = (double)((fix)(win[1][0] + win[1][2]) / 2) + 0.5;
```

or maybe you want to rewrite the expression entirely. I can't see why this wouldn't do the same as your code (get the average of `win[1][0]` and `win[1][2]` but rounding up) but in a simpler and more efficient way

```
new_pix.r = (win[1][0] + win[1][2] + 1) / 2;
```

Incidentally it seems there are operators defined that take integer values, which is why the `/ 2` in your code doesn't cause the same problem.

Comment: Note that this is in a sense a library issue. The constructor taking double should be explicit and/or the conversion to double should have a name (like to_double). The benefit of using fix(0.5) is that if/when the library is improved to use an explicit constructor the suggested code will continue to work.